# How i can run function after created class in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want call construction function only onсe, after create class and use class methods. How i can doing this in JavaScript? Thanks!

```
var Test=function(){
        //hello(); // why not working? How call?
}

Test.prototype.hello=function(){
        console.log(1);
}

var t=new Test();
t.hello()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dmitriykupriynov/doo6bj0b/

Comment: Aren't you already doing it ?

Comment: just do `this.hello()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In constructor you can access object's methods by `this` keyword:

```
var Test=function(){
    this.hello();
}
```